Prove the following for the given function using Leibniz theorem of successive differentiation.
Prove the following for the given function using Leibniz theorem of successive differentiation.
$$y=(1+x^2)^{\frac m {2}} \sin(m \tan^{-1}x)$$
To prove -
(a) $y_{2n}(0) = 0$
(b) $y_{2n+1}(0) = (-1)^n m\cdot m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-2n)$
Here is some general information regarding the question.

This question is from my maths textbook.

"$m$" is some constant which can assume any real value.

$y_{n}$(0) denotes the value of the $n$-th derivative at $x = 0$.


Now, before I show my work and elaborate what I want to ask, let me show you an example problem. This is just to provide a better clarity for how to approach a problem like this.
Eg - Consider the function $$f = a\cos(\log x) + b\sin(\log x)$$
$a$ and $b$ are real constants.
To prove -
$$x^2y_{n+2} + (2n+1)xy_{n+1} + (n^2+1)y_n = 0$$
where $y_{n+2}, y_{n+1}$ and $y_{n}$ denote the $(n+2)$-th, $(n+1)$-th and $n$-th derivative of $y$.
Now, upon differentiating the function -
$$x^2y_2 + xy_1 + y = 0.$$
Now, by Leibniz theorem, if $y = uv$ are two functions, the $n$-th derivative of $y$ -
$$y_n= ^nC_0uv_n + ^nC_1u_1v_{n-1} + ^nC_2u_2v_{n-2} + ..... + ^nC_n u_nv.$$
Applying Leibniz theorem,
$$x^2y_{n+2} + ny_{n+1}\cdot2x + n(n-1)/2\cdot y_{n}\cdot2 + xy_{n+1} + ny_{n} + y_{n} = 0.$$
Upon simplifying,
$$x^2y_{n+2} + (2n+1)xy_{n+1} + (n^2+1)y_n = 0.$$
Now, we have a general idea how to approach. Let's get back to the original problem -
The equation containing derivatives. Here it is -
$$(yy_{2} - y_1^2)(1+x^2) + 2xyy_1 + m^2(1+x^2)^{m-1}=0.$$
Now, it has multiplication of three functions. I am stuck here. How to apply the Leibniz theorem here and proceed further? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

A more common notation for the n-th derivative is $y^{(n)}$ (LaTeX code: y^{(n)})

Maybe it will be useful directly apply the Leibniz theorem to differentiate the product $y=uv$, with $u=(1+x^2)^{\frac m {2}}$ and $v=\sin(m \tan^{-1}x)$.

If there is no typo, your problem has counterexample. Suppose $m=2$. Then $y=2x$. So $y_{1}(0)=y'(0)=2$. But according to (b), $y_{1}(0)=4$.

wait. if m is some integral value between 0 to $2n$. $y_{2n+1}(0)$
will be zero. also for $y=2x y_{1}(0)=2andy_{2}(0)=y_{3}(0)=0$
if $n$ is 1. this is verified, right? i hope im interpreting you correctly.

I'm saying $y_1(0)=2$ contradicts with (b).

agreed. i think this question in my textbook is faulty. thank you for pointing this out.
